# Is there a way to use SQL Tables as classes or objects in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have to tie database and programming for an assignment and I have an idea for a code but need to make sure that I can use the tables I created in mySQL as my classes or objects in Python.

Example: I use SQL to create a database of houses with specific addresses and zip codes.  A client says they live in zipcode x.  My program should then parse through the database and return all addresses within zipcode x.  Then ideally create a table in SQL with the clients results.

Not the exact assignment but it gets the basic idea across.

Comment: What is blocking you to achieve it? Create a class with properties same as columns in table. Perform queries based on those values.

Comment: On the second thought, I think you are looking for ORM like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an ORM. See [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


create_session = sessionmaker()
Base = declarative_base()


person_autoincr_seq = Sequence('person_autoincr_seq')

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"

    id = Column(
        Integer, 
        person_autoincr_seq,
        server_default=person_autoincr_seq.next_value(), 
        nullable = False, 
        primary_key = True
    )

    name = Column(
        String, 
        nullable = False
    )

    def __init__(self, name,id=None):
        if id is not None:
            self.id = id

        self.name = name
```

Using the db:

```
import logging as log
from contextlib import closing


engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine(
    "postgresql://testuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:5432/testdb"
)

create_session.configure(bind=engine)

try:
    with closing(create_session()) as db_session:
        name = db_session.query(Person.name).filter_by(id=5).one()[0]
except Exception:
    log.exception("Something wrong while querying db")
```

Comment: A list with alternative python orm solutions: https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html